# C++ Returning a 2D array of objects from a function to use in another function

Tags: c++, arrays, function, class, reference

I've been working on a C++ project for school and I've encountered some problems when it comes to 2D arrays of objects. So I have the following class:

```
class mecanice
{
public:

    mecanice();
    ~mecanice();
    ...
protected:

private:
    ...
    MyClass Ob[8][8];
};
```

And I need a method that will return Ob so that I can use it in a method from some other class that will do stuff based on what's in Ob:

```
class doodle
{
public:
    doodle();
    ~doodle();
    void do_stuff(MyClass M[8][8]);
    ...
protected:

private:
    ...
};
```

I've tried all kinds ways of going about it but all of them ended up with compiling errors usually related to pointers. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried to use `typedef MyClass MyClassArray[8][8];` and returning `Ob` as a `MyClassArray`?

Comment: Use `std::vector`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following

```
const MyClass ( * myMagicMethod() )[8] const;
```

Or

```
typedef const MyClass ( *A )[8];

//...

A myMagicMethod() const;
```

The qualifier const is used if you do not want that the array would be changed in a method of other class.

Another approach is to pass the array by reference. For example

```
const MyClass ( & myMagicMethod() )[8][8] const;
```

Or

```
typedef MyClass ( &A )[8][8];

//...

const A myMagicMethod() const;
```

In the method that will process the array the parameter also must be declared like reference.

Comment: Personally, I would use `typedef MyClass (A)[8][8];` (or `typedef decltype(Ob) A;`), and have the function return `const A&`, to clarify that the function is returning a reference (and so the typedef can also be used to declare local variables, if necessary).  That's just personal preference, though.

Comment: Thank you very much, I managed to get it to work now by just passing the array by reference. I didn't know about the sytanx `(&MyMethod())[8][8]` which is why I was getting all kinds of errors. Side question: why is there another `const` at the end? I get a compiler error if I leave it there (using CodeBlocks with MinGW that comes with it btw).

Comment: @GeorgeTodosi As I wrote in my answer you can simplify the syntax by using typedef.:)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return arrays from functions. In your case, a function that looks like:

```
MyClass[][] bar ();
```

is ill-formed.

You can consider to have that function take MyClass[][] as a parameter, instead of returning it as a return value, and filling it appropriately.

```
void bar (MyClass foo[8][8]);
```

You can also return a pointer instead (which is legal):

```
MyClass** bar () { }
```

But you will have to make sure that the memory of the object you are returning a pointer to is persistent (i.e. do not return a pointer to a local variable, etc...).